# Sum of smallest Gross and Net values without using same person twice

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

I have 6 players. All players have a gross score and net score. I want to add up the 2 lowest gross scores and the 2 lowest net scores together but we can't use the same person for both.

I currently have players in column D. I have Gross scores in f and Net scores in h. 6 gross scores under Column f and 6 net scores under Column h. I am currently using

```
SUMPRODUCT(small(f8:f13,{1,2}+SUMPRODUCT(small(h8:h13,{1,2}
```

The issue is the same persons scores are being used in Column f and h. I want it two take the 2 smallest scores from f and do the same with h but not use any Player that was already used in f.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Beta Channel users:

`=SUM(SMALL(F8:F13,{1,2}),SMALL(DROP(SORTBY(H8:H13,F8:F13),2),{1,2}))`

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Excel 2013 and later (entered as an array formula if you don't have dynamic arrays):

```
=SUM(LARGE(H8:H13*NOT(IFNA(IF(MATCH(ROW(1:6),MATCH(SMALL(F8:F13,{1;2}),F8:F13,0),0),1,0),0)),{3,4}),SMALL(F8:F13,{1,2}))
```

but is **very** tightly coupled to your having exactly 6 players

[image: Screenshot illustrating formula result for OP's sample data]

Comment: I put it in and it seems to be just off. I put in real data and it is 3 higher than it should be.

Comment: The answer was prepared on the basis of the data in your OP - I have edited it to show that, for those data, it produces the correct sum.

Comment: Thanks. How do you highlight it show it shows which 4 it is using btw?

Comment: Can you change the data to this and see what you get: Player 1, gross 50, net 49. Player 2, gross 42, net 41, Player 3, gross 49, net 45, Player 4 gross 48, net 43, Player 5, gross 45, net 37, Player 6, gross 46, net 38.

Comment: When I use the formula, it shows 168. When I add it up manually, the 4 best scores should be 165. I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: Your post was for the smallest 2 values from each (starting with gross) NOT THE BEST - the 168 is 42 + 45 (lowest 2 of 6 players' gross) + 43 + 38 (lowest 2 of remaining 4 player's net) (the formatting in my screenshot was added manually)